# Problem while installing geopandas with conda (anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, geopandas

I wish to install geopandas with conda, as it is recommended by the manual.

https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html

I am working on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Python 3.7.4.
I have tried to install geopandas with the following commands:

```
conda install geopandas
conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas
conda install python=3 geopandas
```

But it always end up with this error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. 
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve. 
Solving environment: / failed
```

Another attempt has been made creating an environment:

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config  --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install geopandas
```

And it seems to work. Unfortunately, when trying to import the package in Python, the following error show:

```
>>> import geopandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py", line 109, in <module>
    default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py", line 95, in _default_use_pygeos
    import geopandas._compat as compat
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/_compat.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import (
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter, read_excel
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel._base import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter, read_excel
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers import TextParser
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers.readers import (
  File "/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas._typing import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'DtypeArg' from 'pandas._typing' (/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_typing.py)
```

Would anyone have an idea what is the problem installing geopandas on my device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using anaconda, which comes with a ton of packages installed into your base env from the `defaults` channel, which is incompatible with `conda-forge`. essentially have two options:

1. never use `conda-forge`. Booooo.
2. (my recommendation) delete anaconda. I'd recommend installing [`miniforge`](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#install) (the conda-forge-first version of `miniconda`) and then installing packages only into environments. The only things that should ever be installed in your base env are cross-environment utilities, such as jupyter or IDEs which can select from multiple environments, or something like `mamba` which works directly with conda environments.

   If you do this, make sure you do go ahead and [uninstall anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) - having multiple installations of conda floating around in your path is a recipe for disaster.

The anaconda distribution is an all-in-one package for people who want to get set up with a data science environment out of the box. Unfortunately, polluting your base env leads to big problems down the road if you want to use packages from channels other than `defaults`. If you like using the anaconda package pack, you can always install it into an environment with miniconda, e.g. `conda create -n anaconda -c defaults anaconda`

And if you do decide to start from scratch, if you want to rip off the guardrails and do this much, much more quickly but with harder crashes and worse error messages - use [`mamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)! It's a clone of `conda` written to be lightning fast and run in parallel. Since it's a clone of conda, if you *ever* get an error message in `mamba`, just rerun the command in `conda`. It might just suddenly work, or it might error but give you a much more helpful error message.

Comment: Thank you @Michael-Delgado. I was a bit reluctant to remove my version of anaconda as there are some other software I am using that might require it. However, Creating a new environment with miniconda and installing geopandas in has worked well!

Comment: Ok. Maintaining multiple conda installations is a bit of a recipe for disaster though. If your path variable is set up correctly, then you will have mostly effectively uninstalled anaconda, except any command line apps in anaconda which you don’t have in miniconda will mix and match. This can lead to some super gross and confusing errors. Better would be to install anaconda as an environment in miniconda. You can always set up your shell to activate the anaconda env on startup.

Comment: Consider changing your **base** recommendation to Mambaforge, or at least a [Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge). Miniconda is kinda old hat.

Comment: thanks - that's a great edit

Answer (score 1):

This error your getting is due to dependencies conflict

`Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`

Try creating a new env and install geopandas first, then your other packages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Kenan. I might be wrong, but I think I did create a new environment named geo_env, as mentioned above. Let me know if I forgot something important regarding environments.